# Why are non-finite verb phrases defined as non-finite clauses?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, participle-clauses, participle-phrases, infinitive-clauses, gerund-clauses

Before this question is marked as a duplicate, understand that I am not questioning the classification of a non-finite clause nor asking the generic reason for said classification. I know that the subject is implied; however, I don't understand why that is sufficient justification.

Let's look at an example that doesn't contain a non-finite clause:

> He watched **from the rooftop**.

In this sentence, we have a finite clause ('He watched') and a prepositional phrase ('from the rooftop'). The preposition phrase is functioning adverbially, explaining the way in which he watched. Now, I would like to know how this is any different from the next example:

> He watched **to find his target**.

If I have interpreted the definition of a non-finite clause correctly, I believe that 'to find his target' (something I would ordinarily class as an adverbial phrase) is one of them. According to what I have read, the subject 'he' is implied by the matrix clause. However — and I know this is wrong (I just want to understand) — is it not implied that 'he' is the one watching 'from the rooftop' in the previous example? Why is the first example a phrase, while the second is a clause?

I would also like to add that most accessible English learning resources (available online) scarcely acknowledge the existence of a 'non-finite clause', which makes this especially confusing.

For reference, these are the resources I have read (and understood the most): [1](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/clauses/finite.htm), [2](https://www.twinkl.co.uk/teaching-wiki/non-finite-clause), and [3](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/clauses-finite-and-non-finite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: originally a clause was defined as requiring a finite verb, but now many linguists define clause more broadly and therefore there is the concept of nonfinite clauses.

However, even a nonfinite clause normally needs a verb. "From the rooftop" has no verb.

There is an exception: verbless clauses are clauses where a verb (usually "be") is implicit, e.g. "If necessary" (=if it is necessary) in "If necessary, you can contact me".

Comment: Does that mean that everything containing a verb is classed as a clause (finite or non-finite)? And is a subject always required (implied or evident)? Many posts that I have read seem to reject the need for a subject in a clause, at least for non-finite examples.

Comment: Yes, having a verb is what makes it a clause, whether it has a subject or not.

Comment: In the case of a gerund and an infinitive, where it can fit the subject and object roles, do these also count as non-finite clauses? Using the rule that you say, I believe so, but I thought it was worth checking.

Comment: @MJAda It's clear from https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/clauses-finite-and-non-finite that in "I like to travel" and "I enjoy playing", "to travel" and "playing" are non-finite clauses embedded within the two respective main clauses. I'm not certain whether "travel" in "I can travel" is also considered a non-finite clause, although I suspect it is. / On finite/non-finite, traditionally they were qualities of verbs. Now they are qualities of both verbs and clauses, and some linguists argue that only clauses are finite/non-finite, and no longer apply those terms to verbs.